# How to add a query parameter to apache 2.4.27 ProxyPass?

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, query-string, proxypass

I want to map multiple customer facing URLs to a single internal end-point, but with a query parameter to to identify each customer.

For example customer enters https://external_host/customer1

I want a reverse proxy to forward it as https://internal_host/app?customer=cust1

I have tried the following:

```
<Location "/customer1" >
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule /customer1 /customer1?customer=cust1 [QSA,P]
  ProxyPass https://<internal host>/app
  ProxyPassreverse https://<internal host>/app
</Location>

<Location "/customer2" >
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule /customer2 /customer2?customer=cust2 [QSA,P]
  ProxyPass https://<internal host>/app
  ProxyPassreverse https://<internal host>/app
</Location>
```

The basic proxy works, in that the request is forwarded to the internal server, but the query parameter is not added.

From all the reading I have done, I feel it should be possible to do what I want, but cannot get it to work.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 2):

I solved this as follows:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /app http://<internal server>/app
ProxyPassReverse /app http://<internal server>/app

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/cust1.htm /app?client=cust1.htm [QSA,P]
RewriteRule ^/cust2.htm /app?client=cust2.htm [QSA,P]
```

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` from the question config are ignored, because the `P` in `[QSA,P]` performs the proxy request.

Some additional cases to add query parameter `extraparam=something` to the proxied server:

***Regular expression*** and ***remote server***

if you need to use a regular expression in your rule (first wildcard `(.*)` is replaced by `$1`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/path/to/hook/to/proxy/(.*) http://example.org/$1?extraparam=something [QSA,P]
```

If the proxied server uses ***https***, you should add `SSLProxyEngine On` to the configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
RewriteRule ^/path/to/hook/to/proxy/(.*) https://example.org/$1?extraparam=something [QSA,P]
```